# using simple id not ObjectId with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I want to stock new collections in my bdd mongodb within client side (angular) I have a form to fill and when I click on submit a new collection is saved in mongodb like that :

```
{
    "id": "5ede1268f363436aae8e52b0",
    "firstname": "adam",
    "lastname": "nebli",
    "email": "h@gmail.com"
 }
```

My problem is I want a simple id not like that because I need to use it in my edit method. I want to create a method like that :

```
 void editTemplate ( String id , Template temp) {
 template = repo.findbyTempId(id);
 template.setemail(temp.getemail());
 template.setlastname(temp.getlastname());
 }
```

how can I setup mongo to create collections with simple id not Objectid ?

Answer (score 0):

You can transform the id provided by mongoDB. Use schemas for this: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html

```
    const testSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

        email: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        lastName: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        }
    })

    testSchema.set('toJSON', {
        transform: (document, returnedObject) => {
            returnedObject.id = returnedObject._id.toString()
            delete returnedObject._id
            delete returnedObject.__v
        }
    })

    module.exports = mongoose.model('Test', testSchema)
```